# How to wrap 2 divs into another on on the fly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have 2 divs that I am creating from an array:

```
        $.each(data, function(i,item) {
        $('<img/>').attr("src", item.media_path).wrap('<div class="friend_pic' + item.id + '"></div>').appendTo('.sex');
        $('<div class="friends-name' + item.id + '" id="fname_' + item.id + '" />').html(item.fname).appendTo('.sex');
        });
```

And I want to wrap them all in a div, like this:

```
<div class="sex">... the divs from the each function ...<div>
<div class="sex">... the divs from the each function ...<div>
<div class="sex">... the divs from the each function ...<div>
```

I am using: `$('<div class="sex"></div>').appendTo('.mutual_row');` or:

```
$('.mutual_friends, friends-name1').wrap('<div class="sex"></div>')
```

But they give the wring result wrappin gthem all in one div called `sex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each(data, function(i,item) {
 var container = $('<div class="sex" />');        

 $('<img/>').attr("src", item.media_path).wrap('<div class="friend_pic' + item.id + '"></div>').appendTo(container);

 $('<div class="friends-name' + item.id + '" id="fname_' + item.id + '" />').html(item.fname).appendTo(container);

 container.appendTo('.mutual_row');
});
```